# How can I format numbers in MVC View if number is calculated inside the view and not coming from the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, currency-formatting

I have an MVC View where I can format my data coming from Model using a Display Template in the following way:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DebitTotal, "CurrencyFormatter")
```

so if the number was -1000.00, I get ($1000.00)
and if it was 1000.00, I get $1000

How can I format a number the same way that does not come from the model but instead calculated on a view?

```
decimal creditTotal = 0.00m;

if(condition) creditTotal = creditTotal * option;
```

Now, I need to display it:

```
<td>@creditTotal</td>
```

How can I format it using the same DisplayTemplate or some other way around?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Just need to use the same way as for a Model data:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => creditTotal, "CurrencyFormatter")
```

That just will do it